# what is causing the excess repeated letters?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ascii

It will try different shifts and display them for the user to pick the correctly decrypted word, but I don't understand which part is forcing the added 'ABC' after the first display, and is the shift a problem?

```
number_letter = ''
shift = 1

word = 'ABC '
    # input('Please enter a secret message to get decryption possibilities: ')

while shift < 20:

    alphabet = word

    for letter in alphabet:

        number_letter += chr(ord(letter) + shift)

    print('word: ' + number_letter)
    print('Shift: ' + str(shift))

    shift += 1
    number_letter = word
```

Comment: PyCharm has a nice Debug capability.  Use it and see for yourself.  See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: Yes PyCharm is amazing and usually does the trick, but not this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `number_letter = ''` at last line instead of `number_letter = word`, in order to clear the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Teo already basically answered this. Here's some additional information and code. In your last line, you are setting the variable `number_letter` to `word`, then on the next iteration you are appending the new letters (from `alphabet`) to `word`. Instead, you want to completely clear the variable.

Here is the updated code with the input incorporated.

```
number_letter = ''
shift = 1
word = input(str('Please enter a secret message to get decryption possibilities: '))

while shift < 20:
    alphabet = word
    for letter in alphabet:
        number_letter += chr(ord(letter) + shift)

    print('word: ' + number_letter)
    print('Shift: ' + str(shift))

    shift += 1
    number_letter = ""
```